# Gitlab CI: running the same set of tests on several machines

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

In high performance computing is crucial to have a code tested against many different architectures/compilers: from a laptop to a supercomputer.

Assuming that we have

- **`N`** testing machines/**workers** (each one running `gitlab-ci-runner`);
- **`M` tests**,

what shall be the correct layout of `.gitlab-ci.yml` to ensure that `each` of the `N` machines runs all the tests?

Looks to me that adding just more workers ends up in a `round-robin` like assignment of the jobs.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use tags in your .gitlab-ci.yml and on the runners to distribute your tests to all mashines you want. Gitlab CI is very open to those use cases. I assume that you don't use docker for testing.

To accomplish your goal, do following steps:

1. Install your gitlab-ci-multi-runners on your `N` mashines BUT if the runner ask you for tags, tag the mashine with a specifc name e.g. "MashineWithManyCPUsWhatever". Please use the `gitlab-ci-multi-runner register` command to do so. You can alternatively change the tags in Gitlab on the administration view after registration.
   The type of the runners should be "shared" not "specific".

[image]

2. When you installed and tagged every runner on your mashines, tag you jobs.
   Example:

[image]

Every job will now be excecuted on the specific mashine with the specific tag.
For more Information see [Gitlab CI Documentation](http://doc.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html)

Comment: hi, I ended up doing exactly like so.